# XSD defines three identical types I want to map to one class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xsd

A feed we consume has elements like this:

```
<animals>
<cow>
 <name>Daisy</name>
 <weight>250</weight>
 <age>4</age>
</cow>
<pig>
 <name>45tyyy</name>
 <weight>80</weight>
 <age>2</age>
</pig>
<sheep>
 <name>Lamby</name>
 <weight>50</weight>
 <age>7</age>
</sheep>
</animals>
```

An XSD might look like this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="animals">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="cow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="weight"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="age"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="pig">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="weight"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="age"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="sheep">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="weight"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="age"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However in our C# code (and database) they are simply animals of different types so it would be far easier for us if the feed was of the form:

```
<animal type="cow">
 <name>Daisy</name>
 <weight>250</weight>
 <age>4</age>
</animal>
```

or:

```
<animal>
 <type>Cow</type>
 <name>Daisy</name>
 <weight>250</weight>
 <age>4</age>
</animal>
```

We want to use automatic tools like XSD.exe or XSD2Code to generate classes mapping to the XML so we just have one `Animal` class we can deal with.

We can't change the feed, but we can modify the XSD we use to generate the code if that helps - for instance define a base `<animal>` type which is extended, in the hope the C# classes will then include a base class Animal?

Another option is we could transform the XML to the format we wish against a slightly modified XSD, presumably using XSLT?

I haven't done a lot with XSD or XSLT, especially not in C#; so how *can* I take the input XML and map it to a single `Animal` class using code-generation tools?

Comment: You can't have a base class Animals without changing the feed when using de-serialization.  The feed would require : <animal type="cow">.  So you would have to write your own parse code to read the xml code and put results into the classes generated with XSD.

Comment: I was just thinking if the XSD reused the same `complexType` for each, the auto-generate C# code might reflect that by still creating `Cow`,`Pig`,`Sheep` classes but from a common base. I suppose that depends on entirely on what tool I use and is possibly a bit unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another option is we could transform the XML to the format we wish
>   against a slightly modified XSD, presumably using XSLT?

This would be quite trivial in XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cow | pig | sheep">
    <animal type="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </animal>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

No XSD is required for this.

Comment: Yeah I just meant I'd tweak the feed XSD to provide an `<animal>` type so I can auto-generate a C# `Animal` class?

Comment: Any chance you can extend your answer how I might get apply this transform given a `string xml=...` in C# (.net 4.5)

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about that.

Comment: No problem, I'm sure there is a SO question on that

Comment: I finally got to test this on the real XML and it works perfectly. Thanks.